# How to use generic type parameter with Hibernate 5?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-ogm, hibernate-5

Below are the class definition

**interface**

```
public interface myInterface{

    void myMethod1();

}
```

**MyClass1 Class which implements above interface**

```
 @Entity
 public class MyClass1 implements MyInterface{

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    // Getter and setter

}
```

**MyClass2 Class which implements above interface**

```
 @Entity
 public class MyClass2 implements MyInterface{

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String field3;
    private String field4;

    // Getter and setter

}
```

And finally the entity class which has a list with type parameter.

```
@Entity
public class MyClass{

    @Id
    priviate int id;
    private String field5;
    private String field6;
    private List<? extends MyInterface> mylist;

    //getter and setter

}
```

The generated class I'm looking at would look like something like below.

**MyClass Table**

```
-------------------------
id | field5 | field6
-------------------------
1  | abc    | def
2  | abc    | def
3  | abc    | def
```

**MyClass1 Table**

```
-------------------------
id | field1 | field2 | myclass_fk
-------------------------
1  | abc    | def    | 2
2  | abc    | def    | 2
3  | abc    | def    | 1
```

**MyClass2 Table**

```
-------------------------
id | field3 | field4 | myclass_fk
-------------------------
1  | abc    | def    | 3
2  | abc    | def    | 1
3  | abc    | def    | 1
```

I tried to use `@OneToMany` on the list with targetType to MyInterface but it failed with error not a entity class.

**EDIT**

Can it be achieved with Hibernate OGM, preferably using graph or Mongo (document) based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve this using [@ManyToAny](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-many-to-any) annotation, though I needed to modify the class bit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Hibernate does not know from which table to load "mylist" when loading MyClass. 
Take a look at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/inheritance.html.